# Power supply logging on HP DL360 G6

Tags: logging, windows-server-2012-r2, hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

We have a HP DL360 G6 server connected to APC Back-UPS 1100 (BX1100CI-RS). The server sometimes unexpectedly reboots (administrator gets the "select the reboot reason" window after logon). According to UPS s/w PowerChute Personal Edition, only some electrical noise was detected an hour before the reboot.

Is there some kind of power supply logging to make sure what's going on with PSU?

Comment: This sounds like you should contact HP support.

Comment: Nah, this time I should contact the corporate with an advice to invest more in UPS. Current one is not for servers: I had an opportunity to test it on-site after I posted my question. Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware logs on HP servers can be accessed through HP iLO. If you don't know the IP address for iLO, reboot the server and have a look at the POST-BIOS screen. It's displayed there. Else, configure it in the BIOS.